# Ruby on Rails: How do I correctly define a method in the model to total up a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying total up all "amount" columns with a definition in the model like so:

```
  def self.total
    self.all.collect(&:amount).sum
  end
```

With that, "Recipe.total" works as expected. However, I'm using a plugin that passes "Recipe.find(:all)", and I can't seem to pass that to the method to find the total. That is:

```
Recipe.find(:all).total # doesn't work
```

Is there a way to define the method in my model differently to make Recipe.find(:all).total work like Recipe.total?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write your method as:

```
def self.total
  self.sum(:amount)
end
```

And then you can use it also with named scopes:

```
Recipe.total # without any scopes
Recipe.my_custom_named_scope.total # with your custom named scope
```

Another variant is to override find method for that model:

```
def self.find(*args)
  result = super
  if args[0] && args[0] == :all
    def result.total
      self.sum(&:amount)
    end
  end
  result
end
```

Then you get exactly what you want, you'll be able to write `Recipe.find(:all).total`.

Comment: Thanks so much lest. Is there also a way to make Recipe.find(:all).total work as well, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Thank you lest for the great answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Calculation Module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html)

It has methods for: sum,average,count, etc ...

Its baked into ActiveRecord.

So you would want to write:

`Recipe.sum(:total)`

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks so much Jonathan. The plugin passes me a Recipe.find(:all), so would there also be a way to make Recipe.find(:all).sum(:total) work too?